# No connections shown in new xib file

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I am trying to add a new view to a working nav controller app. I edited the DetailViewController.h and DetailViewController.m files for the new view (shown below), created a new DetailViewController.xib file, added the web view. 
My issue is that I cannot link the file owner to the webview. when i control drag from file owner to the webview, the webview label does not show up, it seems like the xib is not connected to the .h and .m

```
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
          IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
       }
          @property(nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *webView;

         -(IBAction) goBack:(id)sender;
        @end
```

the top of .m is
       #import "wwgt3AppDelegate.h"
       #import "DetailViewController.h"
       #import "RootViewController.h"
       @implementation DetailViewController
       @synthesize webView;

Comment: Xcode3 or Xcode4? If the former, you may need to save your .h file(s) and/or force IB to reload header files for IB to know about the new IBOutlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the class of the file's owner to `DetailViewController`, so that Interface Builder knows what outlets are available. You do this in IB, in the Inspector window.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was the step I was missing. It all works now.

Answer (score 0):

First check the type of the owner in IB. If it's set as DetailViewController, try this syntax for a change:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
          UIWebView *webView;
       }
          @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```